# How found Nestable multilevel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-nestable

I found this https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable and use it in my project

But the project has more levels than Nestable support.

How to modify Nestable for unlimited nesting?

I looked in Google but found nothing.

I ask you not to offer other solutions than Nestable.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? do you have any code so that we can reproduce your issue or how you use the library? Please have a read at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$('.my-lists').nestable({
    maxDepth: 7
});

maxDepth - https://github.com/dbushell/Nestable#configuration